# What are some ways to detect the fundamental frequency in a signal using without using FFT?

Tags: fft, wavelet

I am trying to estimate the fundamental frequency in a signal to corroborate the result which I have got by FPGA implementation of an FFT algorithm. Hence, could someone give me some idea how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

- Count the time interval between zero-crossings (if the waveform/SNR allows...).
- Autocorrelation, average magnitude difference function and their variants (YIN...).
- Estimating the parameters of a damped sinusoids model (MUSIC/ESPRIT).
- Several instances of Goertzel algorithm, or more generally other filterbanks (band-pass, comb) - in case there is only a small number of candidate frequencies that you want to discriminate.

Comment: Could you give me some sources or links to papers using these algorithms ?